# ReactiveSwift not working with Xcode 8.1. Conversion to Swift 3 leads to >50 errors. Fixes?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift3, frp

I'm trying to get ReactiveSwift to work with Xcode 8.1. Xcode claims ReactiveSwift was written in an earlier Swift version than 3.0 (I thought it was updated to Swift 3!). Conversion to Swift 3 leads to  >50 errors all in the ReactiveSwift swift files. Any ideas how to fix? I am using CocoaPods to add the ReactiveSwift framework. My pod file is....

## Podfile

```
target 'MyTarget' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'ReactiveSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift.git'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. I tried that and reran pod install . It tells me it is using ReactiveSwift 1.00-alpha.3 and Result 3.0.0. Xcode still insists I convert to Swift 3. I let it update as recommended. Build then gives 58 errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I solved it! I updated Cocoapods from 1.0.1 to 1.2.0.beta.1. Followed the process suggested by @Rob and voila! no errors. After struggling with the major syntax changes in ReactiveCocoa 5.0 and sparse documentation (so far), I got the UI binding test to work using a label and textfield and ..... textField.reactive.continuousTextValues.observeValues { text in self.label.text = text as String!} .....Thanks to @Rob for his help and support!

Answer (score 2):

With CocoaPod 1.1.1, Xcode 8.1, and Swift 3, if I do the following steps, it works fine:

1. `pod repo update` (you only have to do this once)
2. Start with Swift 3 project.
3. `pod init`
4. Add `ReactiveCocoa` line to my `Podfile`.
5. `pod install`, which grabs (right now) ReactiveSwift (1.0.0-alpha.3) and Result (3.0.0).
6. Open the `.xcworkspace`.

The only way I can get the behavior you describe is if I try to add it to an Objective-C project without any Swift code. In that case, it would appear that when you fire up the workspace, it doesn't find the legacy version setting (because there were no Swift build settings at all!) and incorrectly assumes it has to do the conversion. But if I add even a single Swift file to my project before performing the above steps, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. I went back and to be sure created a new swift project. Same outcome. 58 reactiveswift errors - lots of "Argument labels '(error:)' do not match any available overloads. Also 4 reactivecocoa errors. Could there be a bad setting in my Xcode 8.1(8B62)?

Comment: I looked through my build settings. Too many for me to know what they should be! Three caught my eye.... Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries is set to "No', Install Object-C compatibility header is set to 'Yes', and Use Legacy Swift Language Version is set to "unspecified". Sound right?

Comment: FWIW, I'm also using Xcode 8.1 (8B62), and I just create blank iOS "Single View Application", choose Swift, close the project, perform the steps above, and it works. No settings changes were necessary. I did get a message suggesting that I update to recommended settings, and did, and it still worked.

Comment: Here is what I tried Rob, It gave same exactly same outcome. I restarting mac. I created a fourth project. Followed your process exactly. Same result. I created a fifth project and since my Xcode behaviors is clearly different from yours I changed a setting to see if it changed Xcode behavior - Embed Swift Standard Libraries is set to "Yes". Ran through your process, Same outcome. This is very frustrating, I had ReactiveCocoa working just fine a few months ago. Thanks again for trying to help me!

Comment: OK I solved it! I updated Cocoapods from 1.0.1 to 1.2.0.beta.1. Followed the process and voila! no errors. After struggling with the major syntax changes I got the UI binding test to work using a label and textfield and ..... textField.reactive.continuousTextValues.observeValues { text in self.label.text = text as String!} .....Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you don't want to use beta software, I'm using CocoaPod 1.1.1, and it seems to be working. But I won't blame you if you decide that you're going to leave well-enough alone.

Comment: @KeithRussell - BTW, I'd suggest you go ahead and [post an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that other people don't have to pour through these comments in they're stumbling over the same issue. You can then accept your own answer (I will take no offense in this case).